# Perl - getlogin, getpwuid, and $<

Tags: function, perl, authentication, testing

Wanted to understand the example line of code given @ [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getlogin.html) for `getlogin`

`$login = getlogin || getpwuid($<) || "Kilroy";`

It seems like it tries to get the user name from `getlogin` or `getpwuid`, but if either fails, use `Kilroy` instead.  I might be wrong, so please correct me.  Also, I've been using `getlogin()` in previous scripts - is there any difference between `getlogin()` and `getlogin`?

What is this code safeguarding against?  Also, what purpose does `$<` serve?  I'm not exactly sure what to search for when looking up what `$<` is and what it does.

---

**EDIT**
found this in the special variables section - still don't know why it is needed or what is does in the example above

```
$<
```

> The real uid of this process.
>   (Mnemonic: it's the uid you came from,
>   if you're running setuid.) You can
>   change both the real uid and the
>   effective uid at the same time by
>   using POSIX::setuid(). Since changes
>   to $< require a system call, check $!
>   after a change attempt to detect any
>   possible errors.

---

**EDIT x2**

Is this line comparable to the above example?  (it is currently what I use to avoid any potential problems with "cron" executing a script - i've never run into this problem, but i am trying to avoid any theoretical problem)

`my $username = getlogin(); if(!($username)){$username = 'jsmith';}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly right. If `getlogin` returns false it will test `getpwuid($<)` if that returns false it will set `$login` to "Kilroy"

`$<` is the real uid of the process. Even if you're running in a setuid environment it will return the original uid the process was started from.

**Edit** to match your edit :)

`getpwuid` returns the user's name by the UID (in scalar context, which would be the case here). You would want `$<` as an argumnent in case the program switched UID at some point (`$<` is the original one it was started with)

Comment: What's the `$<digits>` bit about? It doesn't seem to refer to anything in the original question. Does it relate to something that's since been edited out of the question by CheeseConQueso, or what?

Comment: thanks for the info.  @gareth - `$<digits>` has been edited out

Comment: thanks for the edit, sorry to switch it up on you.  I'm still a bit confused.  doesn't `getlogin();` return `jsmith`, for example?  if so, then does `getpwuid;` also return `jsmith` if `jsmith` was the original user to start the process?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing it's guarding against is the fact that on some systems, in some circumstances, `getlogin` can fail to return anything useful. In particular, `getlogin` only does anything useful when the process it's in has a "controlling terminal", which non-interactive processes may not. See, e.g., http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663562.

I think the fallback of "Kilroy" is just for fun, though in principle `getpwuid` can fail to return anything useful too. (You can have a user ID that doesn't have an entry in the password database.)

Comment: `getlogin()` can return nothing but **what is worse** is when it returns the "controlling terminal" username. For example in a (unix) terminal `su` to root. `getlogin()`'s return value would be the user prior to `su` and not root.

Comment: @bliako That's the intended purpose of `getlogin` -- to follow the username through `su`, typically for display or logging.